# Not able to sort in JQGrId

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which I am populating with the local data but when try i try to sort the data nothing happens . I have tried below mentioned ways as well
1 Using onSortCol
2 sortname and sortorder

```
function Gridcall() {
        debugger;
        $('#JqGrid_table').jqGrid(
            {
                dataType: 'local',
                sortable: true,

                colNames: ['SLA', 'Type', 'Subject', 'Segment', 'Status'],
                colModel: [
                    {
                        name: 'SlaField',
                        index: 'SlaField',
                        formatter: 'showlink',
                        sortType:'string'

    },
                    {
                        name: 'TypeField',
                        index: 'sort',
                        formatter: 'showlink'

                    }

                ],

                sortname: "SlaField",     
                sortorder: "desc"


    }

            );
```

HtMl code

```
    <div>
    <table id="JqGrid_table" class="scroll">
        <tr>
            <table id="table1"></table>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button id="btn">Get</button>
    </div>





</body>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML for `JqGrid_table` with sample data. Update your question above.

Comment: I just have a simple html page with a table element .

Comment: Can you please prepare a working example with data? You can use jsfiddle.net. Your example is not full and contain some not correct settings. Also it is important to note which version of jqGrid is used.